# Issue in action button when clicked

Tags: r, shiny, dt

In the below application, when I click on action button ("sam") a table appears. Now when you click on small arrow that is there on second column, a modal box pops up. That is fine.

Now when you change the date and click the button, the table refreshes. Now when you click on the arrow, nothing pops up. No sure why?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

number_compare <- data.frame(replicate(2, sample(1:100, 10, rep=TRUE)))
# number_compare$direction <- ifelse(
#   number_compare$X1 < number_compare$X2,
#   as.character(icon("angle-up")),
#   as.character(icon("angle-down"))
# )

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(box(width = 12, solidHeader = TRUE,
               DTOutput("example_table"),
               actionButton("sam","sam"),
               dateInput("da","Date", value = Sys.Date(), min = Sys.Date()-1, max = Sys.Date()+1))
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
                    sidebar,
                    body
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  number_compare$X2 <- paste("sd",number_compare$X2)
  
  number_compare$X2[which(rownames(number_compare) == 2)] = paste(with(number_compare, X2[rownames(number_compare) == 2])," ", " ",as.character(actionLink(inputId="ang", label="", icon("caret-up"))))
  
  print(paste(with(number_compare, X2[rownames(number_compare) == 2])," ", as.character(actionButton("ang",""))))
  print("Vinay")
  # number_compare$X2[which(rownames(number_compare) == 4)] = paste(with(number_compare, X2[rownames(number_compare) == 4])," ", as.character(actionButton("angle2","", icon("angle-up"),style = "border: none;
  #   outline:none;background:white")))
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$sam,{
    if(input$da == Sys.Date()){
      output$example_table <- DT::renderDT({
        datatable(
          number_compare[c(2,3:4),],
          escape = FALSE
          ,options=list(preDrawCallback=JS(
            'function() {
     Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());}'),
            drawCallback= JS(
              'function(settings) {
       Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}')))
      })
    }
    else {
      output$example_table <- DT::renderDT({
        datatable(
          number_compare[c(2,5:10),],
          escape = FALSE
          ,options=list(preDrawCallback=JS(
            'function() {
     Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());}'),
            drawCallback= JS(
              'function(settings) {
       Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}')))
      })
    }
  })
  
  # tolisten <- reactive({
  #   list(input$ang, input$da)
  # })
  observeEvent(input$ang,{
    if(!is.null(input$da))
    {
      print("clicked")
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "dsd"
      ))
    }
  })
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hey user11740857, welcome to stackoverflow! Please try to reduce the lines of code in your example to a specific section. This will help people better answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to unbind

```r
body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$head(tags$script(
    HTML(
      "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('unbindDT', function(id) {
        var $table = $('#'+id).find('table');
        if($table.length > 0){
          Shiny.unbindAll($table.DataTable().table().node());
        }
      })")
  )),
  fluidRow(......
```

and in `server`:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) { # add the 'session' argument

  ......

  observeEvent(input$sam, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("unbindDT", "example_table")
    if(input$da == Sys.Date()){
    ......
```