# data table uiOutput disappears on redraw

Tags: shiny, datatables, dt

I am displaying widgets within a DT datatables in an R Shiny app.

Following a similar approach to [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/01/adding-action-buttons-in-rows-of-dt-data-table-in-r-shiny/), widgets are inserted as text into the data table. Then using the option `escape = FALSE`, the text of the widgets is interpretated as HTML and the widget is displayed.

This approach has worked very well, until I came to redraw the datatable. On redraw the widgets within the table no longer appear. You can test with the following example. When "Redraw" is clicked, the UI output showing the text "here" disappears.

```r
# UI
ui = fluidPage(
  actionButton("draw", "Redraw"),
  # uiOutput("ui"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("classify_table")
)

# server
server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$ui = renderUI({ p("here") })
  
  output$classify_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    df = data.frame(
      rows = input$draw,
      UI = as.character(uiOutput("ui")),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    
    DT::datatable(
      df,
      escape = FALSE,
      options = list(
        dom = "t",
        preDrawCallback = DT::JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
        drawCallback = DT::JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
      )
    )
  })
}

# run
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My best hypothesis is that Shiny ends up with two `uiOutput("ui")` bound. This would mean it does not display at the `uiOutput("ui")` in the redrawn table.

- Supporting this hypothesis: if we uncomment `uiOutput("ui")` from line four, then the text "here" never appears in the data table, just like after redrawing.
- Contrary evidence: the whole point of the callbacks is to unregister the previous `uiOutput("ui")` and to reregister the new `uiOutput("ui")` which should prevent this cause.

Any idea what is causing this behavior and how to fix it? Even suggestions for how to better debug this behavior would be helpful.

Another possible solution is to bind the UI component to shiny directly, instead of in the callback. But I don't know how to determine the JavaScript for this.

Comment: You have to "unbind" before redrawing. Search in my answers with the **[dt]** tag and the keyword **unbind**.

Comment: Thank you @Stéphane Laurent. I've written the below answer based on your work, with attribution, and upvoted the answers I referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment from @Stéphane Laurent, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68560286/7742981) answer by them (search term `user:1100107 [dt] unbind`).

I inserted this code into the UI

```r
tags$script(HTML(
      "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('unbindDT', function(id) {
        var $table = $('#'+id).find('table');
        if($table.length > 0){
          Shiny.unbindAll($table.DataTable().table().node());
        }
      })"
  ))
```

and this code at the start of the `DT::renderDataTable({`:

```r
session$sendCustomMessage("unbindDT", "classify_table")
```

Note that if working in a module, we need to wrap with `ns` as so:

```r
session$sendCustomMessage("unbindDT", ns("classify_table"))
```