# R Shiny checkboxes do not update with observeEvent

Tags: javascript, r, checkbox, shiny, dt

I have a datatable with checkboxes in Shiny. For my reproducible example I took the `iris` dataset.
On the table on the left side you can click on the checkboxes. On the right side it is shown simultaneously whether a checkbox is clicked. This works quite well so far (column "select1" is set to TRUE).
The problem is that after selecting another species as input and clicking on the update button, the content of right table is updated, but not the output of the checkboxes. The selected input of the checkboxes remains the same after the update.
This picture shows the first selection of the checkboxes, which is displayed as "TRUE" on the right table:
[image]
After clicking the Update button, the right table is updated, but the "TRUE" values in column "selected1" remain the same:
[image]

Here is my example app:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

species <- c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")

shinyApp(
  
ui <- navbarPage(
title = div(
  HTML(paste0("<br><b>","My Shiny Web-App","</b>"))
),
collapsible = TRUE,
tabPanel(
  title =  h6(HTML("Tab1")),
  (
    fluidRow(
      column(2,
             sidebarPanel(
               width = 12,
               selectInput(
                 inputId = "myTextInput1",
                 label = h5("Select species"),
                 species
               ),
               h5("Data"),
               actionButton("update",
                            "Load / update data",
                            icon = icon("download"),
                            style="color: #fff; background-color: #E74C3C")
             )
      ),
      column(5,
             mainPanel(
               width = 3,
               fluidPage(
                 div(dataTableOutput("table"), style = "font-size:75%")
               )
             )
      ),
      column(5,
             mainPanel(
               width = 3,
               fluidPage(
                 tableOutput("table_download")
               )
             )
      )
    )
  )
)
),

server<-function(input, output, session) {
  
  shinyInput<-function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
    inputs <- character(len)
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label=NULL, ...))
    }
    inputs
  }
  
  shinyValue<-function(id, len) {
    unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
      value <- input[[paste0(id, i)]]
      if (is.null(value)) FALSE else value
    }))
  }
  
  rv1 <- reactiveValues(bad=NULL,good=NULL)
  
    observeEvent(input$update, {
      rv1$data_filter = iris %>% filter(Species == input$myTextInput1)
      
      rv1$table = data.frame(
        rv1$data_filter,
        select1 = shinyInput(checkboxInput, nrow(rv1$data_filter), 'select_1', value=FALSE)
        )
    })
    
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable({rv1$table},
                    selection = "none",
                    escape = F,
                    rownames= FALSE,
                    options = list(
                      preDrawCallback=JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                      drawCallback=JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '),
                      autoWidth = T
                    )
      )
    }
    )
    
    table_download <- reactive({
      data.frame(
        rv1$data_filter,
        select1 = shinyValue('select_1', nrow(rv1$data_filter))
      )
    })
    
    output$table_download <- renderTable({table_download()})
}
)
```

I want the output of the checkboxes to update automatically with the click on the button.

My guess is that this problem might be due to the following options:
`preDrawCallback=JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'), drawCallback=JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')`

Can anyone help me?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Search *"unbind"* in my messages.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I don't quite understand. Where should I look?

Comment: Click on my name and search "unbind" with the search bar at the top of the screen, with my user id.

Comment: I found a working solution based on your answers (see below). Many thanks @StéphaneLaurent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to apply this answer to my case and solve my problem:
[Issue in action button when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68555784/issue-in-action-button-when-clicked/68560286)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

species <- c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")

shinyApp(
  
ui <- navbarPage(
tags$head(tags$script(
    HTML(
      "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('unbindDT', function(id) {
        var $table = $('#'+id).find('table');
        if($table.length > 0){
          Shiny.unbindAll($table.DataTable().table().node());
        }
      })")
  )),
title = div(
  HTML(paste0("<br><b>","My Shiny Web-App","</b>"))
),
collapsible = TRUE,
tabPanel(
  title =  h6(HTML("Tab1")),
  (
    fluidRow(
      column(2,
             sidebarPanel(
               width = 12,
               selectInput(
                 inputId = "myTextInput1",
                 label = h5("Select species"),
                 species
               ),
               h5("Data"),
               actionButton("update",
                            "Load / update data",
                            icon = icon("download"),
                            style="color: #fff; background-color: #E74C3C")
             )
      ),
      column(5,
             mainPanel(
               width = 3,
               fluidPage(
                 div(dataTableOutput("table"), style = "font-size:75%")
               )
             )
      ),
      column(5,
             mainPanel(
               width = 3,
               fluidPage(
                 tableOutput("table_download")
               )
             )
      )
    )
  )
)
),

server<-function(input, output, session) {
  
  shinyInput<-function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
    inputs <- character(len)
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label=NULL, ...))
    }
    inputs
  }
  
  shinyValue<-function(id, len) {
    unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
      value <- input[[paste0(id, i)]]
      if (is.null(value)) FALSE else value
    }))
  }
  
  rv1 <- reactiveValues(bad=NULL,good=NULL)
  
    observeEvent(input$update, {
      session$sendCustomMessage("unbindDT", "table")      

      rv1$data_filter = iris %>% filter(Species == input$myTextInput1)
      
      rv1$table = data.frame(
        rv1$data_filter,
        select1 = shinyInput(checkboxInput, nrow(rv1$data_filter), 'select_1', value=FALSE)
        )
    })
    
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable({rv1$table},
                    selection = "none",
                    escape = F,
                    rownames= FALSE,
                    options = list(
                      preDrawCallback=JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                      drawCallback=JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '),
                      autoWidth = T
                    )
      )
    }
    )
    
    table_download <- reactive({
      data.frame(
        rv1$data_filter,
        select1 = shinyValue('select_1', nrow(rv1$data_filter))
      )
    })
    
    output$table_download <- renderTable({table_download()})
}
)
```